# How can i fix the root directory of Froxlor?

Tags: apache2.4

Migrating Froxlor from a Debian 7 to Debian 8 System.
I have now the problem, that the auto-generated vhost file of Froxlor, has vhost's in it which reference to the wrong directory. Is it possible to change them to the correct destination?

They referencing to **/var/www/admin** but now i only want them to reference to **/var/www**. I could not find it in the Database of Froxlor nor in the config Files nor in the Webinterface Settings of Froxlor itself.

The reason to change it is that I have a froxlor installation listening on *www.example.com/froxlor* and phpMyAdmin on *www.example.com/phpmyadmin*. Now I want my Overview-Page running on *www.example.com*.
This is the file which is not correct generated. (I replace the IP's and ServerName's)

```
# vhosts.conf
# Created 25.09.2016 15:31
# Do NOT manually edit this file, all changes will be deleted after the next domain change at the panel.

Listen 192.168.0.1:443
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/admin/"
 ServerName **
  FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/3384.ssl-fpm.external -socket /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/froxlor.panel-**-php-fpm.socket -idle-timeout 1000
  <Directory "/var/www/admin/">
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
     AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
     Action php5-fastcgi /fastcgiphp
      Options +ExecCGI
    </FilesMatch>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  Alias /fastcgiphp /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/3384.ssl-fpm.external
 SSLEngine On
 SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLHonorCipherOrder On
 SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
 SSLVerifyDepth 10
 SSLCertificateFile /root/froxlor-ssl/cert.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/froxlor-ssl/key.pem
 SSLCACertificateFile /root/froxlor-ssl/root_trust_chain.pem
 SSLCertificateChainFile /root/froxlor-ssl/root_trust_chain.pem
</VirtualHost>


Listen 192.168.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/admin/"
 ServerName **
  FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/34d3.fpm.external -socket /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/froxlor.panel-**-php-fpm.socket -idle-timeout 1000
  <Directory "/var/www/admin/">
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
     AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
     Action php5-fastcgi /fastcgiphp
      Options +ExecCGI
    </FilesMatch>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  Alias /fastcgiphp /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/34d3.fpm.external
</VirtualHost>


Listen [::1]:443
<VirtualHost [::1]:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/admin/"
 ServerName **
  FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/e36f.ssl-fpm.external -socket /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/froxlor.panel-**-php-fpm.socket -idle-timeout 1000
  <Directory "/var/www/admin/">
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
     AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
     Action php5-fastcgi /fastcgiphp
      Options +ExecCGI
    </FilesMatch>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  Alias /fastcgiphp /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/e36f.ssl-fpm.external
 SSLEngine On
 SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLHonorCipherOrder On
 SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
 SSLVerifyDepth 10
 SSLCertificateFile /root/froxlor-ssl/cert.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/froxlor-ssl/key.pem
 SSLCACertificateFile /root/froxlor-ssl/root_trust_chain.pem
 SSLCertificateChainFile /root/froxlor-ssl/root_trust_chain.pem
</VirtualHost>


Listen [::1]:80
<VirtualHost [::1]:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/admin/"
 ServerName **
  FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/fae9.fpm.external -socket /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/froxlor.panel-**-php-fpm.socket -idle-timeout 1000
  <Directory "/var/www/admin/">
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
     AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
     Action php5-fastcgi /fastcgiphp
      Options +ExecCGI
    </FilesMatch>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  Alias /fastcgiphp /var/www/php-fpm/froxlor.panel/**/fae9.fpm.external
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to disable the root directory auto creation of froxlor? And use this solution. http to https

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName **
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag display_errors off
            php_admin_flag display_startup_errors off
        </IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =**
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName **
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website/silex/web/
        <Directory /var/www/website/silex/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex /index.php
                FallbackResource /index.php
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag display_errors on
            php_admin_flag display_startup_errors on
        </IfModule>
 SSLEngine On
 SSLHonorCipherOrder On
 SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
 SSLVerifyDepth 10
 SSLCertificateFile /root/ssl/cert.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/ssl/key.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The Alias Config Files:

```
# froxlor default Apache configuration

Alias /froxlor /var/www/froxlor/

<Directory /var/www/froxlor/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
You can set it up in the Webinterface under ips and ports. And edit the Ip Adresses their.

**Ressourcen/IPs and Ports/Optionen | Edit**

Their is the userdefined document root for the Website.

It was not under System Settings.

Comment: it would be nice of you if you accept your own answer indicating that the solution was found